# My image won't show via CSS, only in HTML and I can't scale it via CSS

Tags: html, css

So, I want an image to cover the width of the screen but my CSS code isn't working in order to do that nor can I link the image through CSS so it displays on the page, it only shows when in HTML. I have other images showing fine via CSS so not sure why this won't if you can help. And please help to why it won't be the width of screen. Please note I'm a beginner.

```css
#aboutuspic {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<section id="aboutuspic">
  <div class="container">
    <img src="inside.jpg" />
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple - just do this:

```css
#aboutuspic{
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<section id="aboutuspic">
        <div class="container">
        <img src="https://cdn.mos.cms.futurecdn.net/42E9as7NaTaAi4A6JcuFwG-320-80.jpg"/>
        </div>
</section>
```

I think this is what you mean. The issue was that you needed to specify that it *has* to take up the whole width of the viewport.

I hope this helps you,
Tilier

Comment: Thanks Tilier. This has centered it and but for some reason the width isn't right up to both ends of the screen. There is like a 5cm gap on each side?

Comment: This is due to default CSS styling. Simply add this to your CSS:
* {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

Comment: The image still doesn't cover the full width of screen? I put the margin: 0; padding: 0; like you said in the first section of the CSS and then the second section of CSS you put... but still no effect.

Comment: Make sure you put the margin: 0; padding: 0; in *{}. If it still doesn't work, add it to body{}.